# When a choice is inputted nothing happens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not to sure on how to actually put my question into words.

This code is part of a dice game that I made. When the game starts the user has a multiple choice option which is this:

`Please enter 'n' if you are a new user, 'e' if you are an existing user, or 's' to display scores, or 'f' if you forgot your password:`

e.g If the user enters the letter `n` it would let them make a new account for the game and then I would call the function `ens1` to give them the choice to do something.

The problem I have is that if the user enters `n` to make a new account after they create the account I call the function `ens1` to give them the choice to do something else and say that they want to start the game by entering `e` nothing happens for some reason and I have no idea why this is happening.

```
def ens1():
    global ens
    print("\n")
    ens = input("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user, 'e' if you are an existing user, or 's' to display scores, or 'f' if you forgot your password: ")
    while ens not in ('e', 'n', 's', 'f'):
        ens = input("Please enter 'n' if you are a new user, 'e' if you are an existing user, or 's' to display scores, or 'f' if you forgot your password: ")


if ens == "f": # f stands for forgotton password
    #code here
    ens1()


if ens == "e": # e stands for existing user
    #code here
    ens1()


if ens == "n": # n stands for new account
    #code here
    ens1()


if ens == "s": # s stands for scores
    #code here
    ens1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that execution doesn't start over again from the top after you call `ens1()`, ie. if the user presses `'s'`, then

```
if ens == "s": # s stands for scores
    #code here
    ens1()   # <=== after this call...
    # <============ code continues here (not at the top)
```

It's considered bad from to use global variables for state (i.e. the current user choice). It's also unnecessary - just make your function return the user choice:

```
def ens1():
    ens = " "   # don't use global variable (cannot be an empty string ;-)
    prompt = """
      Please enter 

         'n' if you are a new user, 
         'e' if you are an existing user, 
         's' to display scores, 
         'f' if you forgot your password

      or 'q' to quit: """
    while ens not in 'ensfq':
        ens = input(prompt)
    return ens
```

and then use the result of the function in a while loop:

```
while True:
   ens = ens1()
   if ens == 'q':
       break  # exit if the user presses 'q'
   elif ens == "f": # f stands for forgotton password
       print('f chosen')
   elif ens == "e": # e stands for existing user
       print('e chosen')
   elif ens == "n": # n stands for new account
       print('n chosen')
   elif ens == "s": # s stands for scores
       print('s chosen')
   else:
       print('unknown option chosen:', ens)
```

*update:*  `ens = ""` (the empty string) doesn't work, since

```
"" in 'ensfq'
```

is always true.  Changing it to `ens = " "` (i.e. a single space) makes it work.

Comment: When I enter one of the letters it gives the choices to me again, it is stuck in a infinte loop for some reason so could you please help

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that once the user first goes through your en1 loop, the next line of code that executes is for example, "n" for the new user. Then en1 will execute to get the user input, which for example is "e". BUT, remember that the function en1 got called within the `if(en=="n")` scope. So the program will just terminate because the condition was met.

What you need is a continuous loop.

thebjorn's answer is correct. The loop will terminate once the user enters "q"